# Moving a child around inside of it's parent

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a parent control with a child inside.
Now I want to be able to move that child around inside the parent by

1. Clicking on it to pull it around
2. Clicking somewhere on the parent to start pulling it around from the click location
3. Click somewhere on the parent or child to set the child to the cursors position

I defined one MouseDown event for the parent and child that initially moves the child and then attaches a MouseMove Handler to the child and parent. The child and parent also have a MouseUp Handler that removes the MouseMove handler. I want the MouseUp to be called even if MouseUp occurs outside of the window or if the window is alt+tabbed away.

Here is my code, which is basically working, but unreliable. I often end up in the situation where MM (MouseMove) is attached, yet MouseUp or MouseDown can't be called anymore, essentially deadlocking my application. One way to end up in that state is

1. pressing on the parent/child
2. alt+tabbing to another window
3. releasing the mouse while hovering on the other window

**How do I correctly implement this behavior of moving the child inside of it's parent?**

My child is called slider.
This code is in the code behind of my parent, which is a custom control I am working on.

```
    slider.MouseLeftButtonDown += MD;
    MouseLeftButtonDown += MD;

    slider.MouseUp += MU;
    PreviewMouseUp += MU;

    private void MM(object sender, MouseEventArgs meva)
    {
        double percentage = meva.GetPosition(this).Y / this.ActualHeight;
        if (percentage <= 0)
        {
            Percentage = 0;
            slider.Margin = new Thickness(0, -2, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (percentage >= 1)
        {
            Percentage = 1;
            slider.Margin = new Thickness(0, this.ActualHeight - 2, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Percentage = percentage;
            slider.Margin = new Thickness(0, meva.GetPosition(this).Y - 2, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    // MouseDown Handler
    private void MD(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture(); // might be unnecessary?
        MM(sender, e); // initial movement of child
        this.CaptureMouse(); // To enable MouseUp outside
        this.PreviewMouseMove += MM;
        slider.PreviewMouseMove += MM;
    }
    // MouseUp Handler
    private void MU(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        this.PreviewMouseMove -= MM;
        slider.PreviewMouseMove -= MM;
    }
```

Picture related, what I am working on:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the element you want to drag in a `<Thumb>` which has a DragDelta event with HorizontalChange and VerticalChange in the event data. Have a look [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/19/715-using-the-thumb-control-to-drag-objects-on-a-canvas/)

Comment: Thumb comfortably takes care of all the event handling, but is there some way to stop it from accumulating HChange & VChange values in one drag operation with multiple stops? Like if I move it 3 units down and there are three events the first has VChange 1, the second 2 and the third 3 when I'd like all three of them to be 1 each (with all event Vchange values summed up resulting in the value of moved units). Right now I always save the last hc and vc values and subtract them during actual usage. I set them to zero on DragStarted.

Comment: That's odd, as you can see in the example in the link, the event data usually contains only the delta since the last delta - exactly what you need. And it seems to do so for me. Maybe edit your question or open a new question for that with all your code.